# How to instantly load component using useState() in NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm designing a header, with a title that loops over a sentence and renders each word. I am doing so in NextJS, which makes it quite difficult when considering there are server components and client components, since I am a beginner. My problem starts when I implement useState() in my component.

Here is my component code:

```
"use client";

import classes from "./Header.module.scss";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const HeaderTitle = () => {
  const title = "A service based web development agency";
  const titleArr = title.split(" ");

  const [visibleWords, setVisibleWords] = useState(1); // Starts with "A" already rendered

  // Starts an interval that increments visibleWords until it reaches titleArr.length
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (visibleWords > titleArr.length) return;

      setVisibleWords((prev) => (prev += 1));
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });

  // Makes an array of word elements
  const words = titleArr
    .filter((word, i) => i < visibleWords)
    .map((word, i) => (
      <span key={i} className={classes.HeaderTitleWord}>
        {word + " "}
      </span>
    ));

  return <h1 className="header-1">{words}</h1>;
};

export default HeaderTitle;
```

I added "use client" at the start of the page, and everything works the way I wanted it to, however, there is an initial delay to when the animation begins. I am aware that this is due to it being a client component, however, I would like it to make it so that it starts right away. How can I do this?

Comment: This is due to the time needed for JavaScript to run. It's not specifically a Next.js problem. You could consider rendering the text as it's and animate it with CSS.